# How can I play video on browser using play framework

Tags: html, video, playframework, streaming, playback

I want to play a video on browser from a given path.

I tried `<video>` tag.

```
<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480"
   data-setup='{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : true, "preload" : "auto"}'>
  <source src="public/sample.flv" type="video">
</video>
```

It's neither giving any error nor playing the video.
Flash is working fine in my page.

However `<video>` tag  works good when I write it into simple html.

Comment: Play framework and Scala have nothing to do with how you do things in a browser.

Comment: i have a flv video in public folder. i want to play it when my page browsed by client .

Comment: i tried it using controller... Ok.sendFile("pathof file.flv") but i dont know how to play that stream for end user.

Comment: the video is a static asset... don't burden you play application with serving it. But if you want to serve it using Play... just put it in public directory with other static assets like images, css etc.

Comment: Ok ..... but stil if i am trying  **<video width="400" controls src="sample2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>**
it displays blank screen with media controls only.

Comment: Your browser does not support `<video>` tag. Use the latest version of chrome.